# Kotlin native - Execute an executable

Tags: kotlin, exec, shellexecute, kotlin-native

I am trying to execute a command via bash, for example `konanc`.

In KotlinJVM this would just be using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...")`, or creating a `Process` using the `ProcessBuilder`, however, none of those classes are available in Kotlin-Native, as they are part of the Java libraries.

I tried searching for example code in the documentation and the kotlin-native GitHub repository, but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr No, there is no standard process api for kotlin-native

Well the kotlin std for native is still under development, and i don't think process api will be there anytime soon.

However you could use interoperability with some C process library such as https://github.com/eidheim/tiny-process-library

How-to you will find here https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/INTEROP.md

However there are also POSIX's exec/fork calls you could use to spawn and create new process and i think kotlin-native does include POSIX for linux/windows. https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/platformLibs/src/platform see posix.def for platforms.

Example:

```
import platform.posix.*

fun main(arguments: Array<String>) {
    println("${arguments[0]}")
    execlp("touch", "touch", "${arguments[0]}")
}
```

Calling it with `./file <name>` will create a file that is named after the parameter `name` in your current directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have provided a working example.

Comment: any code after execlp doesn't get executed, is there a workaround?

Comment: println("Hello"), execlp("java", "/usr/bin/java", "-version"), println("Done") . ---- the program ends with printing 'Done'...

Comment: Sorry, for the late answer, but I assume that's because execlp waits for the child process to exit. If the process is something like a browser for example, it'll probably block til the application is closed.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this is the killer app for Kotlin native.  And here is part of the solution using the standard Kotlin API;  This solution still needs the buffering of the dir or date command output, but generally works on Windows yea!

```
import kotlin.native.OsFamily.*
import platform.posix.*

fun main(arguments: Array<String>) {
    println("running")
    if (arguments.size >= 1) {
        arguments.forEach { a -> println(a) }
    }
    val platform  = Platform
    val os = platform.osFamily
    println("os is " + os)
    when (os) {
        WINDOWS -> runWindows()
        else -> runUnix()
    }
}

fun runWindows() {
    val result = execlp("dir", "","")
    println("Ran on windows $result");
}

fun runUnix() {
    execlp("date", "","")
    println("Ran on UNIX")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally one that reads from the called process yea!
Only tested on Windows, I will do unix (aka mac :) ) tomorrow.

```
import kotlin.native.OsFamily.*
import platform.posix.*
import kotlinx.cinterop.refTo
import kotlinx.cinterop.toKString

fun main(arguments: Array<String>) {
    println("running")
    if (arguments.size >= 1) {
        arguments.forEach { a -> println(a) }
    }
    val platform  = Platform
    val os = platform.osFamily
    println("os is " + os)
    when (os) {
        WINDOWS -> runWindows()
        else -> runUnix()
    }
}

fun runWindows() {
    val result = execl("dir", "","")
    //hmm emulate https://gist.github.com/a-cordier/33211eda92b8084a9e7e
    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xbLgZpOBi8
    val fp = _popen("dir", "r") ?: error("Failed to run command: dir")
    val buffer = ByteArray(4096)
    var counter = 0
    println("hmm")
    while (true) {
        val input = fgets(buffer.refTo(0), buffer.size, fp) ?: break
        print(input.toKString())
        //println(counter++)
    }
    println("Ran on windows $result");
}

fun runUnix() {
    execlp("date", "","")
    println("Ran on UNIX")
}
```